# Can I get all methods of a class?

Tags: java, class, methods

Suppose that I have a .class file, can I get all the methods included in that class ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To know about all methods use this statement in console:

`javap -cp jar-file.jar packagename.classname`

or

`javap class-file.class packagename.classname`

or for example:

`javap java.lang.StringBuffer`

Answer (score 70):

Straight from the source: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/
Then I modified it to be self contained, not requiring anything from the command line. ;-)

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

/** 
Compile with this:
C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents\j>javac DumpMethods.java

Run like this, and results follow
C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents\j>java DumpMethods
public void DumpMethods.foo()
public int DumpMethods.bar()
public java.lang.String DumpMethods.baz()
public static void DumpMethods.main(java.lang.String[])
*/

public class DumpMethods {

    public void foo() { }

    public int bar() { return 12; }

    public String baz() { return ""; }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class thisClass = DumpMethods.class;
            Method[] methods = thisClass.getDeclaredMethods();

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(methods[i].toString());
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I replace 'Class' with myClass name?

Comment: You would use it from the command line `java DumpMethods com.mypackage.MyClass`

Comment: You also could replace `args[0]` with `"com.mypackage.MyClass"`. If it's using the default package, you can just use `"MyClass"`.

Comment: @Eng I edited it to be entirely self-contained. As you see, the class DumpMethods has 4 methods (foo, bar, baz, and main) and these are all represented in the output. For some fun, replace `"DumpMethods"` with `"java.util.List"`. :-)

Comment: What about inherited methods? See here in case it's a requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31204747/363573

Comment: Those methods don't belong to the class, they belong to the parent. And if that's the requirement, then sure. You have to go up the chain. Tada!

Answer (score 4):

```
package tPoint;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ReadClasses {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("tPoint" + ".Sample");
        Object obj = c.newInstance();
        Document doc = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new File("src/datasource.xml"));

        Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method e : m) {
            String mName = e.getName();
            if (mName.startsWith("set")) {
                System.out.println(mName);
                e.invoke(obj, new 
          String(doc.getElementsByTagName(mName).item(0).getTextContent()));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Using above code you can read all the methods in the class and pass the parameter as string