# How to display all the available methods of some class(java)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get all methods of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266532/can-i-get-all-methods-of-a-class)

Is there a way to display all the availables methods of some class in java?

Comment: Er... iterate over every single class and use reflection? It should be noted that "Java" is a language--it doesn't have methods. Classes have methods. Ah, you edited. Reflection is still the answer, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

through reflection:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for (Method method : YourClass.class.getMethods()) {
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup.  And `getDeclaredMethods()` will do the same but also show the non-`public` ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to get all information about a class.