# get methods and attributes of a compiled class in JAVA

Tags: java, class

Is it possible to get all the attributes and methods that a .class file contains. I just have access to the .class file and I need to know all the attributes, methods and classes that are contained within that file.

Comment: I have seen somethings about introspection and reflection, but I have heard that what I am trying to do can be achieved by combining the jvm with a command in the command line, but I'm not sure this is right

Comment: What I still not clearly about, from where you want to access this attributes and methods? Are you trying reading from Another Java Project using File I/O or do you trying to access from another class?
If you are trying to access from another class, did you know about Encapsulation? Actually you can access all the attributes and methods that have public modifier at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get all methods of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266532/can-i-get-all-methods-of-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

Comment: easy peasy, that's just what I wanted