# Running java class from string

Tags: java

Is there any way to get this to work

```
String ClassName = "testing";
Classname.main();
```

testing.class is a class in the bin folder
if its important I'm using eclipse

Comment: does String have `main()` method? No.

Comment: You can make this work (just not as displayed in your question but in a slightly different way), the keyword here is reflection. Look at the `Class` class and which methods it provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String aux = (String) (Class.forName("java.lang.String")).newInstance();
```

Then you can do what you want with `aux`, for example calling a static method.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the class like this:

```
public Object withName(String className) {

    try{
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
        Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor();

        return cons.newInstance();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

if you don't know which class it is,to find methods of desired class you can check this post:

[Can I get all methods of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266532/can-i-get-all-methods-of-a-class)