# Dynamic pointcut in spring-aop logging?

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, spring-aop

Is there any way we can do logging using dynamic pointcut in spring aop by scanning all beans in a package and intercepting methods?

Comment: I have no idea how to intercept all methods in a class. i tried only intercepting particular method matches.

Comment: [Use reflection to get all methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266532/can-i-get-all-methods-of-a-class), then work your way up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an aspect that will intercept all public methods of all classes in a particular package.  You can use it as a starting point.

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect{

       @Around("execution(public com.test.model..*.*(..))")
       public void logInvocation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable  {    
        System.out.println("Doing some logging before");
        joinPoint.proceed(); // execute the target method
        System.out.println("Doing some logging after");    
       }
}
```